# Pulling a number and prefix from filename using PHP

Tags: php

I am currently using the following function to grab the product code number for a filename such as "62017 THOR.jpg"

```
$number = (int) $value;
```

Leaving me with 62017

The trouble is some of these files have prefixes which need to be left in place ie "WST 62017.jpg"

So im after
WST 62017

not

62017

Could someone help me, either redo what im using or alter ?

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you're after? Everything until the last digit of the first number, or everything until the last occurrence of a number in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all characters except the numbers from the image name and get only numbers.

```
  $number  = preg_replace("~[^0-9]~", "", $value);
```

Comment: ereg_replace is deprecated oO

Comment: @Andy: It was ereg at first. Shakti Singh changed it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$value = preg_replace('/^(.*\d+).*$/', '\1', $filename);
```

It should replace everything after the first numeric value with nothing, leaving everything in front of it in place. Note that you wont't be able to cast the number to int, then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture everything before the number and the number as well, you can use:

```
$value = "WST 62017.jpg";
$number = preg_replace('/^(.*?\d*)\..*/',"$1",trim($value));
// $number is "WST 62017"
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/qENIU)